# .NET Core swagger query string params

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a controller called "FootballControler" with the following endpoints:

- get /api/FeedMatch
- get /api/FeedMatch/ExternalMatchIdAndFeedLeagueId?externalMatchId=0&feedLeagueId=0
- get /api/FeedMatch/ExternalMatchIdAndFeedTypeId?externalMatchId=0&feedTypeId=0
- get /api/FeedMatch/feedMatchId=2
- get /api/FeedMatch/MatchId=3
- get /api/FeedMatch/dateMatch?dateMatch="2012/1/1"

As you can see, all of the endpoints trying to get a list of FeedMatch. What I want to do is to have them like this :

- get /api/FeedMatch
- get /api/FeedMatch?externalMatchId=0&feedLeagueId=0
- get /api/FeedMatch?externalMatchId=0&feedTypeId=0
- get /api/FeedMatch?feedMatchId=2
- get /api/FeedMatch?MatchId=3
- get /api/FeedMatch?dateMatch="2012/1/1"

My solution:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<Match> GetAll()
{
  return a list of matches. 
}

[HttpGet]
public List<Match> GetByMatchIdAndFeedLeagueId(string externalMatchId, int feedLeagueId)
{
  return a list of matches. 
}

[HttpGet]
public List<Match> GetByExternalMatchIdAndFeedTypeId(string externalMatchId, int feedTypeId)
{
  return a list of matches. 
}

[HttpGet]
public List<Match> GetByFeedMatchId(int feedMatchId)
{
  return a list of matches. 
}

[HttpGet]
public List<Match> GetByMatchId(int feedMatchId)
{
  return a list of matches. 
}
```

But Swashbuckle fails in asp.net core with NotSupportedException exception.

I don't want to have one method with optional parameters like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<Match> Get(int? feedMatchId = null, int? feedMatchId = null,string externalMatchId = null ..... )
{
  return a list of matches. 
}
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thank you

Comment: GetByFeedMatchId and GetByMatchId have identical definitions (a GET to the controller with feedMatchId).

Comment: This is by design and limited by swagger. You need to change the `[HttpGet]` with specific action name. Otherwise, you need to merge them into one method with optional parameters.